# Error 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, pandas, django-views

This one is really confusing me. I am reading a excel file into my python script. When I run the script with about 9 rows it runs perfectly. When I run it with 10 rows it gives me this error. I looked the error up and it seems the solution is to use HttpResponse. I am already using the HttpResponse.

```
    io = BytesIO()

    writer = ExcelWriter(io)


    data.to_excel(writer, 'Results', index=False)
    data2.to_excel(writer, 'Suggestions', index=False)
    writer.save()
    rFile = io.getvalue()
    response = HttpResponse(rFile ,content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={FilePath}.xlsx'
    return response
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Here is the error

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/page_objects/

Django Version: 3.1.2
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e0185446\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\e0185446\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\e0185446\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /page_objects/
Exception Value: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

If you think any other part of my code would be useful to see let me know and I will edit it in.

Comment: You make two `return`s, so the second will not run at all.

Comment: Did not know that two returns would cause issues. I removed the 2nd one. It did not resolve the error.

Comment: Which `ExcelWriter` are you using?

Comment: I am using pandas for my ExcelWriter.

Comment: Used about 4 different set of data. The error only happens when I go from 9 rows of data to 10.

Answer (score 0):

I overestimated my ability and ensured myself that the error had to do with the return response part of my code. I found some QOL for my code I left behind that did not work that was causing the error. Thank you everyone for trying to help.